# Redireccionar cuando se pulsa un boton en Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, login

estoy haciendo un login y register en laravel con vue. La idea es que cuando pulse el botón de registrarte, te redireccione al login y cuando pulses el boton de login, te redireccione al home (obviamente si se cumple).

Este es el controlador, se supone con la instrucción de return, te mandaría al login, pero no lo hace.

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request){
    $user = User::create($request -> validated());
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Y este es el fragmento de codigo de la vista en vue, donde mando por axios el request al controlador

```
axios.post('/register', this.form)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Por que no me redireccionara y como lo puedo hacer que funcione? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas realización una petición POST mediante Javascript, por lo que el servidor siempre te devolverá un valor pero por mucho que trates de hacer un redireccionamiento no te va a funcionar.

En este caso debes hacer el redireccionamiento en tu lado de cliente, en este caso cuando haces la llamada POST.

Antes de nada tendrías que cambiar la respuesta de tu controlador.

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request){
    $user = User::create($request -> validated());
    
    if($user) {
      response('El usuario se ha registrado correctamente', 200)
    } else {
      response('El usuario no se ha podido registrar', 403)
    }
}
```

Puedes obtener más información de `response` en la [documentación oficial de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#creating-responses)

Una vez modificada la respuesta del lado de servidor procedemos a manejar los datos en el componente de Vue

```
axios.post('/register', this.form)
  .then((response) => {
     // Si se cumple el registro redireccionas el usuario al login.
     window.location.href = "/login";
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     // En caso de que no se complete el registro muestra el mensaje de error que necesites
     console.log(error);
  });
```

De este modo que si se devuelve un error en el servidor podrás gestionarlo con VueJS con facilidad desde la petición axios.